# Py graph variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, apache-spark

I have a quick question and am very new to this. I have a declared variable:

```
crimeCountByGun = crimeRobbery.map(lambda x : (x[8], (int(x[11]), 1)))
print "List of crimes:", crimeCountByGun.take(10)
```

If you do a `crimeCountByGun.take(10)` you get the following... ( years range 2012-2015 and yes or no).

```
List of crimes: [(u'No', (2012, 1)), (u'No', (2012, 1)), (u'Yes', (2012, 1)), (u'No', (2012, 1)), (u'No', (2012, 1)), (u'No', (2012, 1)), (u'No', (2012, 1)), (u'No', (2012, 1)), (u'No', (2012, 1)), (u'No', (2012, 1))]
```

I'm having trouble trying to do a graph by year and counts for both yes and no. Do I need to declare more to make it easier?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, pay attention to code indentation to make things readable, also it's not quite clear what exactly you're asking (to me at least).